# Array index out of bounds exception case turning up

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class bazar
{
    void calculate ()
    {
        int sum=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi ! welcome to out advance calculator");
        System.out.println("Enter the number of items that you wish to compute");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        String item[] = new String[c];
        int price[] = new int[c];
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i=1; i<=c; i++)
        {
          System.out.println( "please enter the item name : " );
          item[i] = sc.nextLine();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println( "please enter the price of " +item[i]+":");
          price[i] = sc.nextInt();
          sc.nextLine();
          sum=sum+price[i];
        }
        //display part 
        for (int k=1; k<=c; k++)
        {
            System.out.println(  "ITEM                       PRICE");
            System.out.println (item[k]+"                  "+price[k]); 
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("YOUR BILL TOTAL HAS COME TO----------------->"+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed, not 1-indexed. Your for loop should be: `for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)`

Comment: Please don't ask us to debug code for you... Read the rules. Furthermore, use code tags. Finally, welcome, but you need to tell us what you attempted and the exact error from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int price[] = new int[c];
sc.nextLine();
for (int i=1; i<=c; i++)
```

You're creating an array with c indexes. Let's assume c is 10. That means your indexes are 0-9, for a total of 10 indexes. You then loop up to *and including* c. In our example, that means you'd try to access index 10- but the highest index is 9.

You want this instead:

```
for (int i=0; i<c; i++)
```

Comment: i tried this it still gave the same error !!

Comment: You have this same error in several places in your code.

Comment: could you please tell me what corections to make ?

Comment: I already did. You have to learn how to debug your code. What line is the error happening on? Why is it happening? Take a look at my answer and compare it to your code.

Comment: i did as you said but now when i ask for number of purchases it gives me one less input

Comment: This isn't the place for discussion, but look at my code. It starts at zero and ends before the size of the array.